# how to connect oracle database with rest api in android?

Tags: android, oracle

In android studio how to get the rest api web services url link from the servlet program those connected with oracle database and how to connect the oracle database for the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy, either you can use the `HttpConnection` or some third party libraries like Retrofit. I would recommend using Retrofit. That is great and very easy. 
But the hard part in your case is to create the RESTful API. So first you need to learn creating a RESTful API using Java. I guess you should go with the Framework Spring.

Learn more about it here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Once you have all the RESTful APIs for your need. You can use it very easily in your android project.

First create your API Interface

```
public interface Api {


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("createuser")
    Call<DefaultResponse> createUser(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("school") String school
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("userlogin")
    Call<LoginResponse> userLogin(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );

    @GET("allusers")
    Call<UsersResponse> getUsers();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("updateuser/{id}")
    Call<LoginResponse> updateUser(
            @Path("id") int id,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("school") String school
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("updatepassword")
    Call<DefaultResponse> updatePassword(
            @Field("currentpassword") String currentpassword,
            @Field("newpassword") String newpassword,
            @Field("email") String email
    );

    @DELETE("deleteuser/{id}")
    Call<DefaultResponse> deleteUser(@Path("id") int id);

}
```

The create the class to get API instance.

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("belalkhan:123456").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://simplifiedlabs.xyz/MyApi/public/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;


    private RetrofitClient() {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public Api getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

Then use this class to perform the API calls.

```
 Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().userLogin(email, password);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

                if (!loginResponse.isError()) {

                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this)
                            .saveUser(loginResponse.getUser());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

You need internet permission to do this.

If you are a beginner then these steps may confuse you a lot. So I would recommend you Watching this **[Complete Retrofit Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxKwuUOLGEc&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hhGfJw-IQCm6kjywmuJX4Rh)** on Youtube. This course covers everything from building RESTful APIs to consuming it in your android project. Every thing is covered step by step with all the details. Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for this,but the data will get from the oracle database it is possible?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, you can get data from anywhere. You can even use Java to build your RESTful API. Try to learn abhit JAVA Spring.

Comment: can u have any example for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.core;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectToOracle {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection connection = null;
    try {

  // Load the Oracle JDBC driver

  String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

  Class.forName(driverName);


//Create a connection to the database

  String serverName = "localhost";

  String serverPort = "1521";

  String sid = "mySchema";

  String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + ":" + sid;

  String username = "username";

  String password = "password";

  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);



  System.out.println("Successfully Connected to the database!");


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

   System.out.println("Could not find the database driver " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {

  System.out.println("Could not connect to the database " + e.getMessage());
  }

 }

}
```